# How to resolve a potential conflict of interest

Tags: freelance-websites

I have recently began developing websites on my own. It is going well but I have run into a problem with a project I am pursuing.

A family member would like me to create a website for the company he works for. However he is concerned that this could be seen as a conflict of interest.

I really want this project, I'd even do it for free to add to my portfolio.

Has anyone dealt with a situation like this? How would you suggest I proceed?

Comment: Can you explain the conflict of interest further and why this would be considered one?

Comment: Never work for family. Just my opinion. There's too much personal history there.

Comment: @Stacey I believe he's simply worried it could be seen as a conflict of interest by his employer because he doesn't want it to be seen as giving me the project as a favor because we are related. There is no other conflict beyond that.

Comment: @Stacey to further clarify, he actually would like to give me the project, not because we are related, but because he and his co-worker (not-related) were impressed by my recent work for other companies. He just doesn't to give the wrong impression in hiring me

Comment: I would rather see it as getting a job from a reference - This "reference" can be anybody  - Friend,ex-colleagues,etc. In this case its a relative. I dont think this should hamper because I essentially see it as subset of networking. further If deliverables etc are documented/based on agreement + if you exceed their expectations - you should be good. Personally,Its just me - I would rather ask for work then money

Comment: @alpha Thanks for your response. I'll see if I can frame it like that and hopefully my relative can not be the point person on the project so it's not perceived as a conflict. Hopefully it will work out.

Comment: I think there is no conflict. The company 'he works for' is not his own. How many time you'll invest in this project ? The company should pay you for your work. Maybe you can make a better price - not more.

Answer (score 2):

Doing it for free wouldn’t help your matter. That would *definitely* be seen as a conflict of interest, and seen as doing a favour for your relative. Instead, approach it exactly the same as you would any other project. Proposal, contracts, deposits—whatever you do normally, do that for this project, and show that relatives have no affect on your approach to business.

Comment: Very good point. I hadn't been in this situation before and didn't view it like that. Thank you for the advice

Answer (score 1):

You're right, there is a conflict of interest. No matter how fair your family member claims to be, there will always be a doubt that you really received the contract based on your merit alone.

This can effect the way others in the company work with you, their attitude when dealing with you. They may not respect your abilities and may feel like you're getting a free ride.

As a result, the best way of dealing with the situation is for the family member to completely remove himself from the decision making process.  He has no say. The decision is handed over to people who have no reason to be biased toward you and if you receive the job, it is based on your merit alone.  Ideally, they should not even know you have a family member in the company. This way, if someone questions how you got the job, you can be 100% confident it was based on your merit.

If your family member can't remove themself from the decision making process,  I would seriously reconsider taking the job or appling at all, since others in the company may not respect you or take your skills seriously.

Comment: That's great information, thank you for the response I really appreciate it.  I'll see if he can manage to remove himself from it, but if not, I will definitely reconsider.  Thanks again